# Ehcache copyOnRead behaviour

Tags: java, copy, ehcache

I have following method which returns data from cache.

`Customer customer = customerDao.findByName("Carl");`

It returns just one `Customer` object with `name="Carl"`. When I make following change:

`customer.setName("Ron");`

and then I call the method again

`Customer customer = customerDao.findByName("Carl");`

It returns null. I dont make any persist or update operations and the cached object is directly changed.
I tried to use copyOnRead attribute in ehcache config but it doesnt help.

```
<ehcache xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
    xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="http://ehcache.org/ehcache.xsd">
    <!-- default configuration -->

  <defaultCache maxElementsInMemory="1000000" 
      eternal="true" overflowToDisk="false" copyOnRead="true" />

</ehcache>
```

Is there any way how to force ehcache to copy objects from cache?

Thank you

Comment: Why can't you do the copy yourself?

Comment: Yes I could but I have too many classes. So I would like to know if there is an easier solution.